# AbortController missing in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, fetch-api, abortcontroller

I am trying to use `AbortController` in TypeScript.

Given this small file:

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
```

I get the following error from TypeScript compiler:

```
src/testAbort.ts:1:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AbortController'.

1 const controller = new AbortController();
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

TypeScript has documentation about [AbortController](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.abortcontroller.html). I also found an [issue from Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19418) which has been resolved by merging a pull request that contains the type definitions for AbortController. So it should be available.

My `tsconfig.json` contains:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "lib": ["ES2018"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src/**/*", "__tests__/**/*", "index.ts"],
  "typeRoots": ["./node_modules"]
}
```

**What I have tried:**

- Upgraded to latest TypeScript 3.7.5
- Setting both `lib` and `target` options in tsconfig as `"ESNext"`.
- Accessing it through `global.AbortController`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because you are missing the value `DOM` in the lib array of your tsconfig.json.
If you check the official repo, you will find the AbortController [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L1904)!